# Build Flavor: Same home to start multiple activities

Tags: android, android-build-flavors

I have a big home activity/fragment class (300 lines). In this main screen, I have a list to let the user access to multiple subscreens.

Thanks to build flavors, I'm able to generate the strings/icons/... resources easily. But when I handle my list onClick and wish to start different activities from the same home file, the compiler is not happy because of the missing file depending on the current flavor.

Is there a way to avoir multiplying the home file for each flavor ?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do something like `if(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.equals("flavor1.app.package")){ return Flavor1Activity.class; }` for each of your flavors, making your call something like `new Intent(this, getFlavorClass());`

Comment: But Flavor1Activity may not exist in all build. Hmmm, I could move this function to a utility class duplicated for each flavor and it could work. Still waiting to see if there are other alternatives. Thanks !